# Sound composition/compilation softwares

Tags: sound

I'm a one man developer company. I'm working on a game for which I need some variety of sounds. I searched online stock music and it does not give me what I'm exactly looking for.

As a desperate and unsatisfied enthusiast and low-budget game maker, I would like to give a try to compose sound myself.

Is there any sound composing software for games available(with some instruments) ? 
I believe I have some good music taste. but, it needs some time to achieve what I need. I'm willing to put this much for my super game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Linux Multimedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) (which, despite its name, also runs on Windows), which is a free open-source music composing software heavily inspired by the commercial [FL Studio](http://www.image-line.com/flstudio/). It comes with a library of instrument samples and a couple of synthesizer plugins. It also supports the VSTi plugin standard, which means that a lot of synthesizer plugins for other composing softwares can be used.

But it doesn't get near the commercial alternatives in regards to feature-set, stability and polish.

By the way: Just having a good taste in music often doesn't mean that you are also able to reproduce your favorite style of music. To really understand how and why certain kinds of music work the way they do, you will have to invest a lot of time into learning music theory. Composing is a skill with a learning curve just as brutal as that of programming or art. When you want to learn how to be a composer, you might want to sign up on [Music Stackexchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Not for free. Composing takes some money.  There are programs like Cubase, Ableton, and Reason for sequencing music. You will want some extra sound libraries though, if you want it to sound any good. This costs quite a bit.  I bought an LA Strings library, some native Instruments libraries, and Stormdrum for drum sounds, and then various other things. I've spent over 2500 dollars on this stuff.  Then you'll probably want a midi keyboard and some decent headphones.